# RAD With Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, generator, scaffolding

I have a question. I'm moving from PHP with Symfony2 to RoR for my next project, with the main priority being RAD when I become fluent in RoR.

What (Ruby/Rails) tools can I use to achieve incredibly fast prototyping and development?

I've read into the Rails generators and such. My team mate has been using Rails for 3 years but doesn't use scaffolding. Does anyone have any gems they use to speed up development time or if scaffolding *should* be used?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your requirements of an incredibly fast prototyping and development environment:

Use **generators** (model, controller and others).

Use **scaffolding** for prototyping and also for created all the right files, etc.

Use formtastic or (even better) **simple_form** to make forms MUCH easier.

Use **rails3+** now the standard.

Use **ruby 1.9.2+**

Use **Devise** for authentication and authorization.

Use **cancan** for roles- admins, read-only, etc.

Use **rubyMine** for more hints than you can imagine.

Use **VI** for cred, `ed` for even more.

Use **mySQL** for your database.

Comment: Excellent answer! Feel free to update if anything else comes to mind. Blown away :)

Comment: Agree on all points except rubyMine. And I think the best way to do RAD is to think about your project (like UML, ...etc), then you go and it's very fast !

Comment: Yeah, rubyMine vs netbeans vs aptana vs vim vs textmate is a battlefield of opinions and I have seen threads with thousands of rants about each (pro and con).  All I can say is that I have used ALL of the above on ALL 3 (win/mac/linux) platforms and rubyMine was the best.  Hard-core vim'ers will differ on this and so I agree to differ. I gave up the discussion a year ago.

Comment: Excuse me but [ed is the standard text editor](http://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed.msg.html), all this vim/rubyMine/... stuff is for kids and kids should be busy getting off my lawn :)

Comment: Luckily I know of mu well enough to +1 and smile.

Comment: You should not use complete scaffolding imo, but just generate your models (create the empty model file and the migration), your migrations etc. I don't like generating controllers, faster to write it yourself than changing/erasing useless stuff.

Comment: I agree with not using scaffolding... once you know rails fairly well...  until then I feel that it's a great tool for laying out a bunch of the conventions that you should follow :)

Answer (score 0):

[Rails Composer](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-composer/) seems to be good all-inclusive collection of highly recommended gems, an easy setup of a fully-featured RoR project.